# JWT Token Authentication - fetch public key from API and use it in TokenValidationParameters in Program.cs of client app

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to implement a Single Sign On API that uses JWT Token Authentication with asymmetric encryption. I've tested the authentication with success on some endpoint of my API.

Now I want to use this authentication into another web app project (client), the problem is I don't know how to import or fetch the public key from my SSO API in configuration in  `Program.cs`.

*SSO API Program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RsaSecurityKey>(provider => {

    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(
        source: Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtConfig:Asymmetric:PublicKey")),
        bytesRead: out int _
    );

    return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("Asymmetric", options =>
{
    SecurityKey rsa = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<RsaSecurityKey>();

    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; // great for debugging

    // Configure the actual Bearer validation
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = rsa,
        ValidAudience = "jwt-test",
        ValidIssuer = "jwt-test",
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true, // <- JWTs are required to have "exp" property set
        ValidateLifetime = true, // <- the "exp" will be validated
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
    };

    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
});
```

**Endpoit to return public key**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("JWK")]
public async Task<string> GetPublicKey()
{
    return _configuration["JwtConfig:Asymmetric:PublicKey"];
}
```

*Client Webapp Program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("Asymmetric", options =>
{
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; // great for debugging

    // Configure the actual Bearer validation
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = --> some way of fetching the publick key from API (https:.../api/JWK),
        ValidAudience = "jwt-test",
        ValidIssuer = "jwt-test",
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true, // <- JWTs are required to have "exp" property set
        ValidateLifetime = true, // <- the "exp" will be validated
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
    };

    // pt a nu-mi mai schimba claims cu acele link-uri xml
    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
});
```

How can I fetch the public key in this stage of building?
Is this the correct way of configuration for using jwt authentication provided by third party app?

Comment: Can this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70347343/share-jwt-token-between-net-core-5-web-api/70360143#70360143) help you?

Comment: @XinranShen Not really, in that example it's used a symmetric algorithm, and the encryption key is known and imported from configuration I think `var secretByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Authentication:SecretKey")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think use `httpclient` to get key from other projects is a good method, Because you can't mare sure if it is safety. If you wanna share key between projects, A common method is to put this key in to a public, safe place. Here i recommend you to use [Azure key vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/key-vault/) or [Azure Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71853588/use-key-vault-to-store-default-connection-string-of-abp-framework/71854836#71854836). If your Api project and another web app project use the same database, You can also save the key into database.

Comment: I can't use Azure or any external deposits, but this might be a good approach also (to have the key stored to a common server) and import it in project

Comment: Ok, But i think it's impossible to use httpclient in DI Container to access endpoint .

Comment: if something like this exists:
var secretClient = new SecretClient(
                        new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
                        new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());

I think it might be a way of fetching from api

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make it work like following, I don't know how bad it is but...

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<RsaSecurityKey>(provider =>
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string pKey = "";
//https://localhost:7206/api/Authentication/JWK -> returns a string with my public key
    HttpResponseMessage response = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7206/api/Authentication/JWK")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        pKey = Task.Run(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
    }

    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(
        //source: Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtConfig:Asymmetric:PublicKey")),
        source: Convert.FromBase64String(pKey.ToString()),
        bytesRead: out int _
    );

    return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("Asymmetric", options =>
{
    SecurityKey rsa = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<RsaSecurityKey>();

    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; // great for debugging
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = rsa,
        ValidAudience = "jwt-test",
        ValidIssuer = "jwt-test",
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true, // <- JWTs are required to have "exp" property set
        ValidateLifetime = true, // <- the "exp" will be validated
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
    };
    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
});
```

Client for test

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Asymmetric")] // Use the "Asymmetric" authentication scheme
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return Ok("Succes!");
    }
```